# IE 11 problem with tests on Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: frontend, virtual-machine, virtualbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm on a Ubuntu VM and i'd like to test with IE11 (or other versions) . 
Do you have any ideas?

Additional thing is that on vm i've docker, so i arrive to ping the vm but i can't reach any ips.

Thanks, Davide

Comment: You can get an official VM for IE11, but I don’t know if it can be run from another VM: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is a product of Microsoft and It can only work properly with Windows OS.
There is no any official way suggested by the Microsoft to install the Internet Explorer on Linux OS.

The best workaround for using IE on Linux OS is to install any Windows OS using virtual machine. Than user can try to access that Windows OS from Linux OS and try to run their tests with IE browser. You could download the Windows Virtual Machine from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), for Free for 90 days.